# Android Studio Native .SO Libraries and ARM virtualisation issue

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, arm64, android-native-library

I have a project targeting ARM64-v8a and Oreo 8.1
It is for a handheld device, not a mobile phone.
The problem is I need to use a few prebuilt .SO libraries. I do not have the source-code only the SO-files.
I only have .so files for the below architectures:
arm64-v8a
armeabi
armeabi-v7a
 (created by 3rd party)

Problem is it is almost impossible to debug on a virtual device, since I don't have x86 compatible libs.
If I select a x86 virtual device the libs will not load as there is no x86 folder.
If I copy libs to a x86 folder. Then the libs will fail because they are not the correct architecture.
If I create a virual arm64 device I can only find images for android version 7.1 (available for download in Android Studio) which is not ideal, and it takes about 10minutes to even start-up the virtual device. It is unworkably slow.

Is there some workaround ??

Thanks,
Best Regards
//Jonas

Comment: You could try to decompile the .so files into C code and compile them into x86 libraries. Here's an Android-specific discussion: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4624/how-do-i-reverse-engineer-so-files-found-in-android-apks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/) emulator with ARM translator: [8.0](https://github.com/m9rco/Genymotion_ARM_Translation) and [8.1](https://www.jianshu.com/p/97b8250f359e). I didn't check first link with 8.1 but it should work too.

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark this as a possible solution, but this seems a bit too complicated for me at this point. Right now I am debugging on the actual hardware device via USB which is of course optimal. But the issue is the device need to stay with me and it limits concurrent work on a team-level as we only have only one device at the moment.

Comment: As for me, the only advantage of the Google's emulator is comfortable work with hw components (sensors, camera, gps ...). Other emulators often work faster, have a newer API version and take less space on disk and memory. Emulator good when you debug logic or UI because pushing apk is quicker and you don't need move your hand out of keyboard/mouse.